# Quickest way to split a string in bash

Tags: string, bash, sed

The goal: produce a path from an integer.
I need to split strings in fixed length (2 characters in this case), and then glue the pieces with a separator. Example : 123456 => 12/34/56, 12345 => 12/34/5.

I found a solution with sed:

```
sed 's/\(..\)/\1\//g'
```

but I'm not sure it's really quick, since I'm really not searching for any analysis of the string content (which will always be an integer, if it's any importance), but really to split it in length 2 (or 1 if the original length is odd).

Comment: It depends on your input really. If you have noticeably large amount of numbers or large numbers, `sed` will be faster than, for example, looping with parameter expansion. If you have just one 10-digit number, parameter expansion is the right choice.

Answer (score 4):

bash expansion can do substring

```
var=123456
echo "${var:0:2}"  # 2 first char
echo "${var:2:2}"  # next two
echo "${var:4:2}"  # etc.
```

joinning manually with /

```
echo "${var:0:2}/${var:2:2}/${var:4:2}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use parameter substitution. `${var:position:length}` extracts substrings, `${#var}` returns length of the value, `${var%final}` removes "final" from the end of the value. Run in in a loop for strings of unknown length:

```
#!/bin/bash
for s in 123456 1234567 ; do
    o=""
    for (( pos=0 ; pos<${#s} ; pos+=2 )) ; do
        o+=${s:pos:2}/
    done
    o=${o%/}
    echo "$o"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

`sed` is enough fast.

---

If we are talking about speed, let's check.
I think `sed` is the shorted solution, but as example I'll take @choroba's shell script:

```
$ wc -l hugefile 
10877493 hugefile
```

Sed:

```
sed 's/\(..\)/\1\//g' hugefile
```

Output:

```
real    0m25.432s
user    0m8.731s
sys 0m10.123s
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r s ; do
    o=""
    for (( pos=0 ; pos<${#s} ; pos+=2 )) ; do
        o+=${s:pos:2}/
    done
    o=${o%/}
    echo "$o"
done < hugefile
```

Working really long time, I've interrupted it at:

```
real    1m19.480s
user    1m14.795s
sys 0m4.683s
```

---

So on my PC Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7500 CPU @ 3.40GHz, MemTotal: 16324532 kB, `sed` making around 426568 (close for half a million) string modifications per second. Seems like fast enough

Comment: actually it's `read` bash builtin which is slow, however as the current process is bash, to split just one variable with sed there will be the overhead to launch  a new process

Answer (score 0):

You can split a string into elements using the `fold` command, read the elements into an array with `readarray` and process substitution, and then insert the field separator using `IFS`:

```
$ var=123456
$ readarray -t arr < <(fold -w2 <<< "$var")
$ (IFS=/; echo "${arr[*]}")
12/34/56
```

I put the last command in a subshell so the change to `IFS` is not persistent.

Notice that the `[*]` syntax is *required* here, or `IFS` won't be used as the output separator, i.e., the usually preferred `[@]` wouldn't work.

`readarray` and its synonym `mapfile` require Bash 4.0 or newer.

This works with an odd number of elements as well:

```
$ var=12345
$ readarray -t arr < <(fold -w2 <<< "$var")
$ (IFS=/; echo "${arr[*]}")
12/34/5
```